# Why is the "exact" keyword in React Router giving me a blank page?

Tags: react-router-dom

I have the code below but only the Home component gets rendered for both '/' and '/join' paths - even after having placed '/' after '/join'.

When I use the `exact` attribute, I get a blank page for both paths.

```
import Home from './Home';
import JoinRoom from './JoinRoom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/join' component={JoinRoom} />
                    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
        )
    }
    
export default App
```

I have included the following dependencies as well:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
```

What can I do to solve this? Thanks.

EDIT: I should add that React Router works fine on a simple React app. My problem is when I try integrating it to Django.

Comment: Did you try to use the exact only on the HomePage path ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried using exact only on the Home page path and used it with and without <Switch> too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Its not working for you (Maybe the way you are redirecting from page to another page).

Anyway I created the same App like you and it's work for me.

Maybe you will able to find the differences.

[Codesandbox for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-stackoverflows-question-fqpsh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for replying. It works as well for me on a plain react app but not when I integrate it with Django. Any advice there?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in Django. Maybe you have any server side router that causing the problem.